# Install the web application in One Click

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, iis, deployment, installation

I have a web application. I need to setup the web application in one click installation.

For example

- Automatically Get the source from SVN or TFS
- Automatically Publish the files
- Automatically create IIS Virtual directory
- Automatically deploy the files
- Automatically create the databases

I have tried  "**Setup and Deployment Project**"  which will come along with visual studio. But it only installs the files and place the bin folder into program files. 
I need to know can i do all the above listed  functionalities through the "**Setup and Deployment Project**"

I know about the installshield. But its a paid version installer, I need a alternate free installer for this process. Please someone suggest me some other open source installers.

Comment: Please  take some learning about `teamcity` and `ruby installer`  :)

Comment: I need a free version or open source

Answer (score 0):

We use [WebDeploy](http://www.iis.net/learn/publish/using-web-deploy/introduction-to-web-deploy)/MSDeploy and TFS builds for one click deployments.

You can use the following MSBuild arguments in the [TFS build to deploy](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/deployment/configuring-team-foundation-server-for-web-deployment/creating-a-build-definition-that-supports-deployment) the build after it is built successfully:

- /p:DeployOnBuild=True
- /p:DeployTarget=MsDeployPublish
- /p:MSDeployPublishMethod=RemoteAgent
- /p:MsDeployServiceUrl=[IP of target server]
- /p:DeployIisAppPath="[Website name in IIS]"
- /p:IncludeIisSettingsOnPublish=true
- /p:UserName=
- /p:Password=

WebDeploy can be configured to deploy your web application [and databases](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd465343(v=vs.100).aspx).

[image]

Comment: I dont have VS on my server. I need a installer  like Setup and Deployment Project

Comment: VS is not required.  You only need WebDeploy installed.

Comment: Instead of TFS can i use Web SVN ?

Comment: You can use WebDeploy with any build system.  SVN is source control only.  You would need to use TeamCity or some other build system to initiate the build.